# HERE Android SDK trial

Tags: android, here-api

I'm using HERE SDK trial and I want to ask that `RealisticViewListener` and `LaneInformationListener` works with trial license? Because I have registered listeners but I don't get any event.

```
navigationManager.addLaneInformationListener(new WeakReference<>(laneInformationListener));

    navigationManager.setRealisticViewMode(NavigationManager.RealisticViewMode.DAY);
    navigationManager.addRealisticViewAspectRatio(NavigationManager.AspectRatio.AR_4x3);
    navigationManager.addRealisticViewListener(new WeakReference<NavigationManager.RealisticViewListener>(realisticViewListener));
```

Comment: Please provide more information? All features should be available for evaluation.

Comment: I have want to get traffic signs like these :[signs](http://www.affordablecebu.com/load/philippine_government/list_of_traffic_signs_in_the_philippines/5-1-0-30228)  to show for the user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both features are available in the trial (as well as **all** other features). Your implementation looks correct, but it will be hard to determine where things go wrong without seeing more code.

Also, please be aware that in rare cases there is simply no lane- or signposts information available, e.g. the callback only occurs when the user has arrived at a point in the route where lane information is available such as before a highway exit.

I suggest to try out the [SDK navigation example](https://github.com/heremaps/here-android-sdk-examples/blob/master/turn-by-turn-navigation-android/app/src/main/java/com/here/android/example/guidance/MapFragmentView.java) on GitHub and hook your listeners in from there to see how it works. You can also start navigation simulation (if you are unsure if your local area has enough data):

```
// if user wants to start simulation, submit calculated route 
// and a simulation speed in meters per second 
error = navigationManager.simulate(route, 60);
```